# Xcode emulator XS: why the border on XS iPhone becomes a rectangle in the screenshot?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I want to save different screenshots of my App on XS iPhone version. Unfortunately I have this problem (Xcode 10.1):

**The screenshot border obtained from simulator (File > New Screen shot):**

[image]

**Expected:**

[image]

So I can't understand why the border image is not like in the simulator?

Comment: If you want to take a screenshot of the window itself press ⌘ + ⇧ + 4 to enter macOS screengrab mode, then press the spacebar. The cursor will change to a camera icon. Then you can click on the window to save a screenshot of it.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIAA Screenshots do not include the simulator border, just the internal screen (without physical cutouts).

If you want to add the Phone frame, I would suggest:

- Adding them manually as required using an image editor for your App Store uploads.
- Look at some of the various iOS Shortcuts available which are supposed to help with this -

https://www.macstories.net/ios/apple-frames-a-shortcut-for-framing-screenshots-from-every-apple-device/

NOTE: I could not quite get this one to work on very quick install.

- Look for an app in the iOS or MAC App Store which allows you to take screen
  shots and add borders automatically.